# Openpyxl How to get row from worksheet by index

Tags: python, excel, indexing, openpyxl

Using Openpyxl and python3.5, I tried getting the first row from an excel worksheet using a subscript but I an error.

```
# after getting filename
# after loading worksheet
# to get the first row of the worksheet
first_row = worksheet.rows[0]

# I get 
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
      first_row = phc_th_sheet.rows[1]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

In relation to getting the first row, I've also tried 
     first_row = worksheet.(row=1)
     # and
     first_row = worksheet.rows[:1]

None worked. Any suggestions or is the feature not available in openpyxl?
I've been to the documentation at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/ but I found nothing helpful enough to index and select rows

Comment: This is covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the documentation:

```
first_row = worksheet[1]
# worksheet[row_index_from_1]
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Yes, we converted `ws.rows` into a generator so that behaviour across different implementations would be consistent and also to encourage this syntax for ad-hoc queries. Programmatic access is best done using `ws.iter_rows()` and, where possible, `ws.iter_cols()`.

Comment: This is now worksheet.rows[1].  Going to update the answer.

Comment: @CharlieClark after the `rows` variable is a generator, do we still have a way to access row by index now?

Comment: @BenLiyanage: I've rolled back your edit. I suspect you were using an older version of `openpyxl`. `worksheet.rows` is a generator, so `worksheet.rows[1]` won't work.

Comment: If version is important, can you please specify it in the answer mark?  Thanks for keeping the answer fresh! I don’t have access to this codebase any more so I do not know what version I was using.

Comment: this no longer works in the newest version

Comment: How can you use this nice syntax to get the values?

Answer (score 22):

The error `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`. Means that you are trying to access by index a generator, which doesn't have one, because it creates the elements as you iterate through it.

You can solve it easily, cast it to a list to get the element you want:

```
first_row = list(worksheet.rows)[0]
```

or iterate thought the rows:

```
for row in worksheet.rows:
    foo(row)
```

This is because, even if both are iterables, lists and generators can behave quite differently, you can get it better explained here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range

Comment: This is not a great answer.  It's better to just get the row directly, rather then explicitly converting the iterator to a list.

Comment: Sure it is. However, as I usually manipulate excel spreadsheets with pandas and I'm not familiar with the internals of openpyxl, just tried to give an explanation of the error and how to get a workaround.

Comment: @BenLiyanage the issue is you cant because the method is now a generator. the list method emulates accessing the row directly. Note that it pulls all the data into memory first. like DOM and StaX considerations, if you have a large dataset you'll want to iterate using the second example.

Comment: Yup, I fixed the other answer.  =D  Happy bug hunting guys!

Comment: I understand @ebt's explanation generators, but I still can't get how one could access to the n_th row with the "second example" presented in the answer.

Comment: @ErdemKAYA I would suggest using the enumerate method. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate you can use an if statement to identify which row to take action on.