# Python- how can I create tuples from rows of excel data

Tags: python, openpyxl

So far, I have been trying to use "openpyxl" to accomplish this task. What I am trying to do is, pull all cell values from rows in an excel sheet and then include those cell values as part of a list of tuples. Here is my code so far:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('work_1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet_cells = []
for rows in worksheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in rows:
        sheet_cells.append(cell.value)

print sheet_cells
```

My results: [1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L]

By doing this, I am including all cell values (regardless of the row they are pulled from) into 1 single list.

What I want to accomplish is, have a list with values from each row included as tuples, like this: [(1L,2L,3L,4L),(5L,6L,7L,8L),(9L,10L,11L,12L)]

In the example above, my worksheet is using 3 rows.

I am a bit stuck (and new to working with Excel data in Python) and couldn't find any similar answers to this type of question. Thanks.

Comment: Try `sheet_cells.append((cell.value))`.

Comment: See this answer for more discussion about grabbing rows from openpyxl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561670/openpyxl-how-to-get-row-from-worksheet-by-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('work_1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet_cells = []
for rows in worksheet.iter_rows():
    row_cells = []
    for cell in rows:
        row_cells.append(cell.value)
    sheet_cells.append(tuple(row_cells))
print sheet_cells
```

Comment: Easier still if you use `ws.values`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Pandas for your work?

```
import pandas as pd

file=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None)
new_list=[]
for i in range(file.shape[1]):
     new_list.append(list(file[i]))
```

Comment: Upvote! I will definitely give this a shot; I have heard that Pandas is really good to use as well.

Comment: yes,Pandas have many great inbuilt function for file manipulation,as you become used to it,it becomes more convenient.